# How to align end of texts or annotations in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to achieve the following figure I can easily realize in gnuplot but, this time, using matplotlib :

[image]

On the right side (here "Recettes"), after reading the documentation, I am confident I can do it easily.

But on the left side, I have to align the ends of the textes and I cannot see any parameters in annotate() or text() function to achieve this.
Any idea would be welcome.

Comment: You can specify `horizontalalignment` or `ha` with one of these [ ‘center’ | ‘right’ | ‘left’ ] as one of the keyword arguments (**kwargs).

Comment: @swatchai Would you mind providing this as an answer which can be accepted, such that the quesiton will not stay unsolved forever?

Comment: OK, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify `horizontalalignment` or `ha` with one of these [ ‘center’ | ‘right’ | ‘left’ ] as one of the keyword arguments (**kwargs).